# json request not parsed in controller correctly

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jersey

i am struggling with something that should work but doesn't...

i have this mapping in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/keys", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseEntity<Void> parseKeyList(keyList keyList) {
  return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

with the simple class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class keyList {
  private String keys;
  public String getKeys() {
    return keys;
  }

  public void setKeys(String keys) {
    this.keys = keys;
  }
}
```

And I am sending this simple JSON post:

```
{"keys": "This is my key list"}
```

but I am getting `null` in the `keys`.

As requested the original dispatcher-servlet:

> ```
>    <context:component-scan base-package="com.api" />
>    <!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/*" location="/WEB-INF/pages/" /> -->
>    <bean
>     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
>     <property name="prefix">
>         <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
>     </property>
>     <property name="suffix">
>         <value>.jsp</value>
>     </property>
> </bean>
> ```

Comment: The get/set methods may need to be named `getKeys/setKeys`

Comment: nop. does't work, still null let me edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't attached your keyList param to the request body, change the method to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/keys", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResponseEntity<Void> parseKeyList(@RequestBody keyList keyList) {
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Btw.: Class keyList should rather be KeyList (with big K).

Also there is (look at the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38475/discussion-between-gleeb-and-dirk-lachowski)) a

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

missing from your dispatcher-servlet.xml. That's the one that is registering the jackson mapper/marshaller.

Comment: getting 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Could you please remove the @Consumes annotation and try again?

Comment: But you have a JAXB marshaller configured?

Comment: not sure... what am i supposed to do to configure it... i just have a jackson mapper as a dependecy

Comment: That's also ok. How are you calling the controller?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38475/discussion-between-gleeb-and-dirk-lachowski)